# Couple Issues with jQuery Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am using jQuery Animate to create a Pan-Zoom effect on an image. Overall it works well with two exceptions.

First it starts the animation and seems to hit a wall then continue to zoom in. Is there a way to prevent this and make the motion one smooth motion.

Second is the motion is a bit jerky, especially at the end. Is there a way to smooth this out? I am using easing on the page if I should try adding some form of easing. (This was testing in Firefox and Chrome and both are jerky.)

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/fsBbr/1/) of the animation.

Notes: I am using jQuery 1.8.3 and I could use CSS but sticking with jQuery for cross browser compatibility. (Majority of my users are on IE unfortunately.)

***HTML***

```
<div style="width:1140px; height:500px; overflow:hidden; text-align:center;">
    <img id="pan-zoom" style="width:900px; height:600px; position:relative; top:-80px; left:0;" alt="European Bee-eaters" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Pair_of_Merops_apiaster_feeding.jpg" />
</div>
```

***JS***

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#pan-zoom').animate({
        width: '2141px',
        height: '1428px',
        top: '-200px',
        left: '-405px'
    }, 8000, function() {
            // Fade In Hidden DIV
    });
});
```

Comment: Position absolute http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/fsBbr/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you speed up the animation, it will appear to be smoother. The slower the animation, the more noticeable any roughness of it will be.

Changing the easing to linear seemed to help as well. The slowness at end of the default easing (swing) makes the roughness of the animation very noticeable. The code below uses linear easing and is sped up twice as fast (as well changing the outer width to 900px, as @loxxy suggested), and it looked reasonably good.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#pan-zoom').animate({
        width: '2141px',
        height: '1428px',
        top: '-200px',
        left: '-405px'
    }, 4000, 'linear', function() {
        // Fade In Hidden DIV
    });
});
```

Getting a large animation to be both smooth and slow may only be possible with hardware support like WebGL. Short of that, choose between smooth and slow, whichever is more important.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Speeding it up some does help quite a bit. I changed from `linear` to `easeInOutQuad` as I think it looks a bit better but this can be personal preference. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<div style="width:1140px; ...
```

To

```
<div style="width:900px; ...
```

The idea is, that before zooming in, the image is scaled to fit the parent width, which is the effect you want to remove.

Updated [fidde](http://jsfiddle.net/fsBbr/3/).

---

EDIT : Or position absolute, as commented.

Answer (score 0):

Both problems would be resolved if you used the scale function of the css transform property. I think (it has been a long time since i've user jquery and did not follow up) that the jquery.animate function is not compatible with these. You should use a plugin or write one that does if you want to keep using jquery.

In your fiddle you use the left, top, width and height properties. This will be especially jerky in webkit.

Jquery transform plugin top google result:
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: I will look into it, however, jQuery Transit while it does look interesting has this to say: `Transit degrades older browsers by simply not doing the transformations (rotate, scale, etc) while still doing standard CSS (opacity, marginLeft, etc) without any animation. Delays and durations will be ignored.`  That unfortunately doesn't work for me. I must support IE 8 and 9.

Comment: IE 9 does use css transforms. On 8 you're stuck with old school animation.